# Replace element in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I've got a LinkedList of guests who are invited to a party. I want to replace one of the guests with someone else. To do so, I am searching the list for the one to delete, deleting it, and adding the new person to the front of the list.

Here's my replace method so far:

```
public void replace(String n, String rn, String rf){
  boolean match = false;
  GuestNode curr = GuestList;
  GuestNode replace = new GuestNode(rn,rf);
  GuestNode onemore, twomore;

  while (match == false && curr != null){
     if (curr.getLink().getName().equals(n)){
        onemore = curr.getLink();
        twomore = onemore.getLink();
        curr.setLink(twomore);
        match = true;
     }
     else
        curr = curr.getLink();
  }

  if (match){
     GuestList = curr;
     addNode(replace);
     System.out.println(n+ " has been replaced with " +rn+ ".");
  }
  else
     System.out.println(n+ " was not found.");
}
```

My trouble is that when I run it, I can find and delete the original, and add the new person to the front of the list, but it keeps losing the rest of it. Here's the output I'm getting (user input in bold):

> Please enter one of the following options: sort, search, replace, delete, print, quit
>   **print**
>
> ten is attending, and they like 10 ice cream.
>   nine is attending, and they like 9 ice cream.
>   eight is attending, and they like 8 ice cream.
>   seven is attending, and they like 7 ice cream.
>   six is attending, and they like 6 ice cream.
>   five is attending, and they like 5 ice cream.
>   four is attending, and they like 4 ice cream.
>   three is attending, and they like 3 ice cream.
>   two is attending, and they like 2 ice cream.
>   one is attending, and they like 1 ice cream.
>
> Please enter one of the following options: sort, search, replace, delete, print, quit
>   **replace**
>
> Who would you like to delete? **three**
>   Who would you like to put in their place, and what is their favorite ice cream flavor?
>   **THIRTYTHREE 33**
>   three has been replaced with THIRTYTHREE.
>
> Please enter one of the following options: sort, search, replace, delete, print, quit
>   **print**
>
> THIRTYTHREE is attending, and they like 33 ice cream.
>   four is attending, and they like 4 ice cream.
>   two is attending, and they like 2 ice cream.
>   one is attending, and they like 1 ice cream.

I've been dealing with this for a couple of hours now, and I can't find where the mistake is. Please help!

EDIT: Here's the code for my GuestNode, in case the problem is in there.

```
public class GuestNode{
    private String name;
    private String fav;
    private GuestNode link;

    public GuestNode(String n, String f){
        this.name = n;
        this.fav = f; 
        link = null;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.name +" is attending, and they like "+ this.fav +" ice cream.";
    }

    public String getName(){ return this.name; }
    public String getFav(){ return this.fav; }
    public GuestNode getLink(){ return this.link; }
    private void setName(String n){ this.name = n; }
    private void setFav(String f){ this.fav = f; }
    public void setLink(GuestNode l){ this.link = l; }

    public void clear(){
        this.link = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to do this: `curr.setLink(curr.getLink().getLink());`

Comment: My professor isn't clear on his instructions, and I assumed this is what he wanted. I tried for a bit to update the information in the old Guest to just become the new Guest, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `GuestList` is the first node, the problem is here:

```
GuestList = curr;
```

This truncates the beginning of the list by making `curr` the first node of the list.

Also, make sure that your code works even in the special case (what happen if you want to replace the first node?)

Comment: That sounds right. I'm assigning GuestList to the temporary curr, making changes to curr, and assigning it back, so I'm losing out on those I've already gone past. If I reassign curr to GuestList though, I'll lose those changes I made. Should I just be making changes to GuestList directly? I was taught to assign it to the temporary holder so I don't mess up the original list.

Comment: You just don't have to assign it back. `GuestList` must not change at all (except in the corner cases), that’s why you use `curr` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. If I'm using curr, and I replace the guy I was looking for, how do I then make sure those changes are kept in the original GuestList?

Comment: `GuestList` is actually the first node of your list, which points to the second node etc, until the node you want to delete. So you’re already changing the original list. `curr` is not a copy of your list, it’s a "finger" that first points to the first node (`GuestList`) and then go forward until you find the node you want to delete.

Comment: Ah!! Now I understand, and now it's working correctly. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 2):

Your actual node code isn't shown here, but that's where the problem is. You've made an oversight in how a linked list works.

Because each node links to the next node, if you simply remove a node, you're also removing all nodes behind that node, since you no longer have a reference to those nodes. Each node only stores the next one, nothing more. So nothing is left pointing to those other nodes.

To remove a node from a linked list properly, you must not only delete that node, but you must go in and update the node BEFORE that node to now point to the node AFTER that node. You have to "patch" the hole that you've created, re-connecting the chain.

Imagine a long chain, and you've just taken out one of the links. If you do nothing else, the chain falls into two pieces, two separate chains. In order to remove a link, you have to join the two links infront and behind it.

A -> B -> C -> D -> E  remove C

A -> B  *_*  D -> E   two chains! second one is lost, no reference to D.

you need to patch them such that the result is

A -> B -> D - > E

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing with the onemore and twomore temporary GuestNodes. The current node's link will now link to the twomore node. I'll add my node code to see if that is the problem.

Comment: And to add to what @Zaphod42 mentioned your `replace` function is not doing an actual replace. You are deleting a node and adding the new node at the beginning of the list. This is not replacing. You should probably consider replacing the information stored in the node that you want to replace

Comment: I think alundy already "patches" the list with `curr.setLink(twomore);`

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how my method doesn't do that. The way I see it:

A -> B -> C -> D
curr = B
onemore = C
twomore = D

curr.setLink(twomore);
A -> B -> D